# How I can use ToolbarItem in Map View

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I use `ToolbarItem` to show menu settings in `View`. In each view works, not only in map view. How I can fix this to see the menu in map view?

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems >
    <ToolbarItem Name="Ustawienia"
    Command="{Binding UserSettingCommand}" Priority="0" Order="Secondary" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <maps:Map x:Name="CurrentMap" Grid.Row="0"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        IsShowingUser="True" MapType="Street" />
    <Button Text="Udostępnij miejsce" Command="{Binding CheckinCommand}" 
    Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,10" />
</Grid>
</d:ExtendedContentPage>
```

Comment: I found a mistake,  
this :   (Application.Current as App).MainPage = new GPSNavigationPage();
I replaced it : await NavigateToPage(new GPSNavigationPage(), false, true);

and code in xamal works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this,

Add this code in your page constructor after `InitializeComponent();` Method.

```
this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Ustawienia", "", () =>
{
           //your stuff 
}, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));
```

Comment: Can I use this in MVVM ?

Comment: why not. you can use in MVVM also.

Comment: something like that ?
`public partial class GPSNavigationPage : ExtendedContentPage
    {
        public GPSNavigationPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

   this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Ustawienia", "", () =>
            {
           
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary));

            InitializePage();
        }

        private void InitializePage()
        {
            BindingContext = new GPSNavigationPageViewModel(Navigation, CurrentMap);
        }
    }`